# how to use auto with a height in css

Tags: css, html

How would you use auto height? I need the hight to be 250px default the auto is working but i cant get a default hight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps [`min-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-height.asp) is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [`min-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_min-height.asp) ?

As [Brian Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135731/brian-scott) rightly said, `min-height` is not implemented in IE6, so you could use a JavaScript expression (see [this blog article](http://perishablepress.com/press/2007/01/16/maximum-and-minimum-height-and-width-in-internet-explorer/)).

```
* html div#mydiv { 
   height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 249 ? "250px" : "auto" ); 
}

div#mydiv {
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Just remember that min-height and min-width are not implemented in IE6. You can double up the style with the IE6 expression syntax if you really need to.